# layout should make use of the available space on 10-inch tablets

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-screen-support

I am trying to check my tablet emulator using this settings below but all my emulators (tablet) aren't working in my Android Studio, and I don't have a tablet to test if all the orientation will be okay with this settings after i got the above notification, so i went ahead and added the code below on my manifest. I read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219583/how-to-make-an-app-tablet-compatible) but I am just want to be sure. So my question is, with the below setting will everything be okay on tablet? and can be download the app on their tablets?

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Comment: What do you mean the emulators arent working? whats happening?

Comment: i mean all the emulators tablet on android studio aren't launching.

Comment: then you have some error in the AVD settings, has nothing to do with your project, unless you never even see the popup window? in which case you most likely dont have a tablet sized emulator set up at all, can you post what you see in the console after clicking launch on the emulator?

Comment: Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Comment: it keeps saying that tries to launch and crushes, all of them but my normal nexus emulator is working just fine, however i still use my phone. Either way i just need more help on what i should add inorder to make the app compatible with tablets.

Comment: go to your AVDManager, edit the configurations for the tablet, reduce the memory size of the device

Comment: In order to make your app compatible with multiple screen sizes you need to create various size folders and according dimens.xml files, in order to get the emulator launching, you need to fix the AVD, no matter what if you launch on an emulator even if your not supporting that screen size it will launch it will just look terrible, please read the info on the Android docs, link provided in @Th3G4m3r answer

Comment: Thank you justin i will work on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a guide on how to support multiple screen sizes by creating multiple layout/values/... folders with different attributes.

For example you could use "layout-large" folder to change the view sizes for 10" tablets only.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

On which devices your app can be downloaded depends on your choice in the Google Play Developer Console which costs 25$ if you haven't bought this yet.

Comment: i already have an app ready i want to configure it with the tablet.